# The more rows a MySQL table has, the longer it takes to find a row

Tags: mysql

Hy ,

I have a innoDB table in MySQL with 70785 rows. I need to find rows by its documentId column and it takes moreless 200 miliseconds for each request. This column has a BTREE index

1. The time that it takes to get a row(200 miliseconds) is normal moreless, right?
2. The more rows there are in the table, the longer it will take to find the row, right? I mean,today the query takes 200 miliseconds but when the table has 20000 rows it will take more time, right?
3. Is there a way to execute a query and it takes always the same time without caring about the number of rows in the table? I think there is not and the onsly solutions is indexing columns
4. My real problem is that I am executing a batch job and I need to read a excel file with many rows and basically,for each row in the file I need to get its documentID value and look for it in the database table. If the file contains 80000 rows for example, it will take 4,5 hours

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean `200K` rows. And yeah, that is gonna be the case unless there is some kind of magic going on in your system :) The query time is proportional to the amount of work you ask to be done, it can not be constant, it depends from the number of operations. I would ask why would you need to always read data from excel? Can't you port it once for all in the database structure to make everything more consistent and reduce the overhead.

The time your query takes depends also on how you perform the search for the specific id. A naive sequential search in the excel file would give you a quadratic complexity overall. Depending on the structure of the file you maybe able to implement a binary search to reduce the complexity to logarithmic.

These are just suggestions, to make more clear conclusions more details should be provided. Anyway I hope this can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on the query, but if it is relatively simple and returning a single row from cache, 200ms sounds high. You need to do an `explain` on your query and find out what it's doing, if it is choosing the proper index, etc.
2. Not necessarily. If properly indexed, a simple query's performance could remain largely the same even with many times more rows.
3. Create proper indexes/schema depending on your scenario
4. I am guessing your excel file reads are going to be your bottleneck here, not your inno queries.

Comment: The query is select * from users where documentId = '16464644545H'. The documentId  column is  VARCHAR(50) and the index is BTREE. Thats all the configuration it has and yes, throwing this sentence in a mysql client takes more miliseconds when the table grows, checked, I dont know what bad configuration I might have in my column or in my query

Comment: do this "explain select * from users where documentId = '16464644545H'" and also "show create table users" and post the results in your original question.